# Singularity of the Jacobian matrix and bifurcation in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-topology, control-theory, vector-fields, bifurcation

Let $$\dot x = f(x), \; x\in \mathbb{R}^n$$ be an ODE and let the Jacobian $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ be singular at the point $x_0$. Is this sigularity sufficient for saying that a bifurcation occurs at $x_0$?

Note: In this question, I am thinking about the role of the "parameter" in bifurcation (i.e., we can define $\dot x = f(x,p), \; x\in \mathbb{R}^n, p\in\mathbb{R}$, where $p$ is a parameter). Particularly, I was thinking what happens if we do not consider any parameter for the vector field, and just look at the singularity of the vector field.

Comment: As far as I know a bifurcation happens when the stability or number of equilibria/periodic orbits change when changing a system parameter. Also a counter example would be when $f(x)$ is just a constant for all parameter values, whose Jacobian is always singular.

Comment: Thanks @KwinvanderVeen ! Your counter example makes sense. I was thinking about non-trivial cases (say $f(x)$ is a non-trivial function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, namely in general a singular Jacobian at an equilibrium point yields an inconclusive stability analysis. For example consider

$$
f(x,p) = -p^2\,x-x^3
$$

which for $p=0$ has a singular Jacobian at $x=0$, but that equilibrium remains stable.